# How to insert a statement (e.g. copyright) which remains visible in mapping window?

Tags: qgis

I have a QGIS workspace that I need to apply a copyright statement to, so we can show data to clients without breaching the terms of our data suppliers.

So far I've attached a label to a point in the bottom left of the area, and styled it nicely, but obviously this disappears when a user pans or zooms away from that point.

Is there a way to keep a block of text always visible in the QGIS window?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You could check out the Watermark plugin for QGIS

https://plugins.qgis.org/plugins/watermark/

Comment: Great idea - only small problem was that the text was hardly visible (being a watermark and all...) but I fixed this by modifying line 59 of watermark_plugin_layer.py from 'painter.setOpacity(0.5)' to 'painter.setOpacity(1)'. If anyone else tries this same trick, be sure to then delete the watermark_plugin_layer.pyc (this is the compiled file and will be regenerated with the changes in place)

Answer (score 8):

There's a "Copyright" decoration option in QGIS already.

View... Decorations... Copyright Label.

Choose text, placement position, colour. Make sure to enable the checkbox. Doesn't have text size or font choice, but the defaults look okay. Use `&copy;` if you want a copyright symbol.

[image]

This is QGIS 2.4.

Comment: Yep - no need for a hack, this function is indeed built in! Thanks!

Comment: Anyway of displaying the copyright notice in print composer and not the main window?

Comment: @Beaver try asking a new question for this.

Answer (score 1):

You can create a text box in print composer and paste in your copyright message. Copy the wording from the main window and paste it in the text editor for your text box.